# How to set listing style within a line

Tags: listings

I would like to have a command to set listing for a word or two within a line of latex.  For example:

The keyword public is used...

I would like to make the word public in java style. Ideally something like this:

```
The keyword \ja{public} is used...
```

I tried:

```
The keyword \begin{lstlisting} public \end{lstlisting} is used...
```

but that does not work.